# Can i add a custom font to androids 4 default typefaces?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I want to make it so I just have to right click on a graphical view and scroll down to typeface and it will display my font.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package fonts in your application for use by your application via the `Typeface` class.

You cannot install fonts into the firmware except by building your own firmware.